# Why does tf.feature_column.input_layer return my feature values in rearranged order

Tags: python, tensorflow

I currently am testing some ideas with `LinearClassifier` with `TensorFlow`'s New API. Have created some features using just `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` and feed them into a `tf.feature_column.input_layer` layer as following:

```
layer_test = tf.feature_column.input_layer(input_fn('data.csv')[0], feature_columns_raw)
```

And then simply check if my input features are corrently fed via:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    layer_test_val = sess.run(layer_test)
    print(layer_test_val)
```

But I found if very strange and counterintuitive that column order in `layer_test_val` were completely changed out of my control. It's no big deal if the `LinearClassifier` can eventually get the decent prediction accuracy despite the rearranged features' order. However, if what I need is the learned weights of those features, how can I make sure that the output of 
`weights = lr_classifier.get_variable_value('logits/kernel')` is in the exact order of the features as they are specified